# Trying to call a variable from a function to another function

Tags: python, function, parameters, return-value

```
def editselection():
  #this converts the text in the files into a list in a list
  with open("stocks", "r") as stocks:
    for line in stocks:
      stripped_line = line.strip()
      line_list = stripped_line.split()
      list_of_items.append(line_list)
    itemselection = input('Choice: ')
    if itemselection.isalpha() == True:
      ManageStock()
    elif itemselection == '':
      ManageStock()
  itemselection = int(itemselection)
  os.system('clear')
  #the square brackets are the indexes so for example if they select 0, the first item turned into a list would be known as specific item
  specificitem = list_of_items[itemselection]
  changeitem(specificitem)
  return specificitem
```

I'm trying to call the variable 'specificitem' to the function AddItem()

```
def AddToCart(specificitem): 
  os.system('clear')
  number = 0
  os.system('clear')
  print ("""Here is the current stock 
--------------------------
Name, Price, Quantity
--------------------------
""")
  with open ('stocks', 'r') as stocks:
    for i in stocks:
      number = str(number)
      print (number+'.' , i)
      number = int(number)
      number = number + 1
  #this converts the text in the files into a list in a list
  with open("stocks", "r") as stocks:
    for line in stocks:
      stripped_line = line.strip()
      line_list = stripped_line.split()
      list_of_items.append(line_list)
    itemselection = input('Choice: ')
    if itemselection.isalpha() == True:
      AddToCart()
    if itemselection == '':
      MakeASale()
  itemselection = int(itemselection)
  #the square brackets are the indexes so for example if they select 0, the first item turned into a list would be known as specific item
  quantity = input('How many would you like? ')
  chosenitem2 = list_of_items[itemselection]
  with open ('cart' , 'a') as cart:
    chosenitem2 = str(chosenitem2)
    cart.write(chosenitem2 + '\n')
  with open("cart", "r") as cart:
    for line in cart:
      stripped_line = line.strip()
      line_list = stripped_line.split()
      list_of_cart.append(line_list)
    with open ("cart" , "r+") as cart:
      data = cart.read()
      data = data.replace(chosenitem2[2], quantity) 
      cart.close
      cart = open('cart' , 'wt')
      cart.write(data)
      cart.close()
    with open ("stocks" , "r+") as stocks:
      data = stocks.read()
      data = data.replace(specificitem[2], chosenitem2[2]) 
      stocks.close
      stocks = open('stocks' , 'wt')
      stocks.write(data)
      stocks.close()
    print(chosenitem2)
```

though it comes up with AddToCart() missing 1 required positional argument: 'specificitem'

I'm trying to use the variable from editselection to edit the quantity for example when the user enters a value it adds it to the file cart and 'subtracts' if you will from the file stocks, the use of global is unavailable due to the fact that I'll just get marked down. I've been stuck on this for 2 days now

Comment: See how to create a [mre] - and especially the **minimal** part of it.

Comment: Remove everything that is not related to the question you asked from your functions.
Nobody has time to read pages of irrelevant code to answer a simple question.

Answer (score 0):

In the first function write `(function name)editselection.(variable name)specificitem=(value)list_of_items[itemselection]`
And on the second function call the variable for example like this:
`print(editselection.specificitem)`
And this will print the value of the variable.
This is called a function variable (or something like this)